# How can I find the total size of the contents of my Trash folder?

Tags: filesystem, trash

Is there any way I can find out exactly how much is in my Trash folder? I can see the size column, but if I have a folder in the trash, it shows the number of items in the folder rather than the total size of the items in the folder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can right click on folders in the trash (and those not in the trash) and select *Properties* to see the total size.

If you want to see the total size of your trash, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to select everything, and then right click and select *Properties*.

[image: Item properties]

Comment: Thanks! For some reason it never occurred to me that I could get the properties of multiple items like that.

Comment: I tried this but it was working for more than a minute without a final total, which is weird. The interim total kept moving up and down, so I don't think it was working properly. I'm using 18.04. The `du` solution showed 2.7 GB immediately.

Answer (score 18):

From a terminal:

```
du -hs ~/.local/share/Trash
```

Answer (score 2):

Select all the elements in Trash folder (`Ctrl + a`), right click and see `Properties`.